# git difftool with meld broken after update to 22.04: fatal: external diff died

Tags: command-line, 22.04, git, meld

After updating to 22.04 recently, this command has stopped working:

```sh
git difftool --tool=meld -y HEAD~1
```

```
Viewing (1/15): 'file.txt'
Launch 'meld' [Y/n]? y
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
fatal: external diff died, stopping at file.txt
```

I've already tried both reinstalling `meld` with `--reinstall` as well as removing it with `--purge` and `--auto-remove` and installing again.  No use.

I've also tried to launch `meld` from the console, but it's breaking as well:

```sh
meld ./file1.txt ./file2.txt
```

```
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Weirdly enough, it seems to be launching fine from the GUI, but that's not what I need.  I need to use it with `git difftool`.

Is this because of Wayland?  Any way I could debug this?

**EDIT:**

Additional info: `meld` installed through `apt`, version `3.20.4-2`.

I've also filed a bug on Launchpad, just in case: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/meld/+bug/1994970.

Comment: How are you installing meld? [from here](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnome.meld)?

Comment: @RobertLongson, no, I'm using `apt` and the default Jammy repositories.

Comment: you could also try installing from source: `git clone https://git.gnome.org/browse/meld ; cd meld ; sudo python setup.py install`

Comment: @RobertLongson, if all else fails, I may try flatpak or installing from source, but for now I would like to avoid that, if that is possible.

Comment: I'm having [the same issue with Beyond Compare](https://forum.scootersoftware.com/forum/beyond-compare-4-discussion/linux-aa/88824-bc4-as-a-git-merge-tool-says-fatal-external-diff-died), on Fedora, though.